# Using LESS source map files in VS 2010

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, less, source-maps, mindscape

I'm using Visual Studio 2010. I'm also using the extension/plug-in [Mindscape's Web Workbench](http://www.mindscapehq.com/products/web-workbench).  It allows you to use LESS in VS, as well as compile and generate source map files. I've never used a source map file, but I know what they do.

My issue is, how do I get my project to use it when I run the page? Do I need to include it in the `<head>`? Or include it somewhere else?

Thanks for helping a noobie out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the moment only **Chrome** seems to support sourcemaps with CSS. See [Working with CSS Preprocessors](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/css-preprocessors) for how to use them there.

**Update**: **Firefox** (v.29+) now supports CSS sourcemaps too. See [Live Editing Less in the Developer Tools](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2014/02/live-editing-sass-and-less-in-the-firefox-developer-tools/)

Comment: Chrome canary now supports sourcemaps with LESS. See http://dev.tutsplus.com/tutorials/working-with-less-and-the-chrome-devtools--net-36636?utm_source=CSS-Weekly&utm_campaign=Issue-95&utm_medium=email